# Are my Spirit Island pages mistakenly uncut?

Tags: spirit-island

I just got Spirit Island, and some of the rule books pages appear to have not been cut:

[image]

Am I missing something here or is the sheet just uncut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's definitely a printing error.  Whether they were originally one page that wasn't cut, or if they got stuck together during the process for some reason, I couldn't say.  But they're not supposed to be stuck together like that.